# How to show $\int_0^1 f^3 dx < ( \int_0^1 f dx )^2 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Assume $f$ is $C^1([0,1])$ and $f(0)=0$ and $ 0 < f' \le 1 $ then I want to show that $$\int_{0}^{1} f^3 dx < \left( \int_{0}^{1} f dx \right)^2 $$

my tries : I want to use a similar way like the proof of the poincare inequality

$f(x)^3=\int_0^1 3 f'(x) f^2 (x) dx $ now I use the bound of $f'$ and $f$ and Holder inequality and integrating from both side of the inequalities but i reach inequalities different of the asked one.

Can some one help me. thanks.

Comment: *Hint:* Consider $g(t) = \left(\int_0^t f(x)\,dx\right)^2 - \int_0^t f^3(x)\,dx$ and compute $g'(t)$ :)

Comment: @r9m: very nice. That boils down to proving that $$\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\,dx \geq \frac{1}{2}f^2(t)$$ that is trivial since $$\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\,dx\geq \int_{0}^{t}f'(x)f(x)\,dx.$$ You should put it as an answer.